# java check a Date instance has the time part

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a `Date` field in my class that can has two types of values: with and without time. Something like this: `2015-01-01` and `2015-01-01 12:00:00`. I want to make formatted string from my date. I know I can use `SimpleDateFormat` class for doing this, but I don't know the format. In fact, If my date has the time part, I must use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format and if my date does not have the time part, I must use `yyyy-MM-dd` format. My question is, **Is there anyway to check a date has time section before formatting it?**

Here is my code:

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

.....

private String formatDate(Date date){
     //I need to something like this:
     if(/* `date` has time part */){
          return dateTimeFormat.format(date);
     }

     else{
          return dateFormat.format(date);
     }
}
```

Comment: A Date is a number of milliseconds. It doesn't have a date or a time part. When converting the date to a string, in a given time zone, then the time part can happen to be 00:00:00.000. You can check that by formatting the Date, or by transforming it into a Calendar object, or, better, by transforming it into a ZonedDateTime object, and then check that the hour, minute, second and millisecond are all equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reliably do that, because once you create a `Date` object, it is represented as a number in milliseconds, which includes the specific time. For this reason you cannot possibly know how the object was built and if the specific time was set.

A workaround would be to check if the hours, minutes and seconds are set to zero. Keep in mind that there is a small probability that the date was parsed as `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, but all these values were set to `0`, simply because the time was indeed `00:00:00`. However, this probability is equal to `1 / (24 * 60 * 60) = 0.00001157407`, so I assume that you can live with that.

Answer (score 2):

## A Big Mess

As shown in the other answers, the old date-time classes bundled with Java such as java.util.Date and java.sql.Date are a mess. They were rushed to market, with bad design decisions. Specifically a java.util.Date represents both a date and a time-of-day, while its subclass java.sql.Date pretends not to have a time-of-day but actually does. The doc explains that you are supposed to ignore this inheritance relationship to help maintain the illusion. Not good.

## java.time

This whole mess has been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### Date-Only

Among the new classes is [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). This is the first class bundled with Java for representing a date only, without time-of-day nor time zone. To determine a date such as "today", you need a time zone (a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)). For example, a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal. **When you need a date-only** value, I suggest you add a member to your class of this type.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

### Date-Time

If you want a date-time, first consider the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. This marks a moment on the timeline in UTC. Almost always best to do your business logic and data storage in UTC. **When you need a specific moment in time** rather than a vague date, add a member of this type to your class.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

For presentation to the user in their desired/expected time zone, apply a time zone to an Instant to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( now , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

### First Moment Of The Day

I do not recommend this strategy, but to directly answer your Question about detecting if the time-of-day in a date-time value happens to be the first moment of the day…

First you need to think about time zone. All of these date-time classes mentioned above track time by a count-from-[epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) in UTC. The old classes count in milliseconds, the new in nanoseconds. The epoch for both old and new is the first moment of 1970 in UTC. So there is **no such thing as a date-time without a time**, as you pose it in the Question. The closest thing to that is a date-time whose time-of-day happens to be the first moment of the day. Seems to be your situation (though my discussion above strongly recommends you change your situation).

How to determine if a date-time has a time-of-day that is the first moment of the day? First you must consider time zone. Either you want UTC or you want a particular time zone such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal). Depends on your business rules.

If starting with a java.util.Date, first convert to java.time.

```
Instant instant = myJUDate.toInstant();
```

Be aware that a date does not *always* start at the time `00:00:00.0`. Because of Daylight Saving Time (DST), and possibly other anomalies, in some places the first moment of the date is a different [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time). The java.time framework can determine this first moment of the day by using the `LocalDate` class and its [`atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) methods.

So after determining the time zone we care about, we adjust our Instant into a ZonedTimeZone.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now ();
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
```

Next we need to see if that is first moment of the day. So we convert to a LocalDate, then back to another ZonedDateTime by calling `atStartOfDay`. Comparing the first ZonedDateTime to the second tells us if the original was indeed at the start of the day. To sum it up: We are converting from *ZonedDateTime → LocalDate → ZonedDateTime*.

```
// Convert to LocalDate, to get start of day, to compare to above.
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate ();
ZonedDateTime startOfDay = localDate.atStartOfDay ( zoneId );
Boolean isStartOfDay = ( zdt.isEqual ( startOfDay ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " for zoneId: " + zoneId + " is zdt: " + zdt + " if compared to startOfDay: " + startOfDay + " is T/F: " + isStartOfDay );
```

> instant: 2015-12-12T23:20:23.560Z for zoneId: America/Montreal is zdt: 2015-12-12T18:20:23.560-05:00[America/Montreal] if compared to startOfDay: 2015-12-12T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal] is T/F: false

If you want UTC rather than a particular time zone, in the code above use the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) as your [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) object. `ZoneOffset` is a subclass of `ZoneId`.

Comment: I think this answer would be better without the "First moment of the day" part, and just saying one should use the proper classes and not doing any time-of-day hacks. Upvoting for the parts before that.

Comment: @eis I do agree with you, as the first part is the right way to go. But the "First moment of the day" part is what more directly answers the Question.

Comment: Yes. Maybe the latter part could be enclosed in [spoiler tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69573/implement-the-spoiler-tag) :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using java.sql.Date which derives from java.util.Date there is no possibility of a Date object not having a time value.
Note the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html
A Date object instance holds a miliseconds value, to be precise the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

Comment: this answer applies to java.util.Date, which is what OP is probably using, equally well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Calendar` object. The calendar can give you structured access to all fields of a `Date` value, i.e. year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, etc. This would allow you to check whether the time fields are non-zero. As JB Nizet stated, the time part can happen to be zero, in which case wou would misinterpret it as a date only value.

Comment: so you tell that doing it this way isn't going to work due to ambigous zero value interpretation, but suggest it as an answer anyway?

Comment: the question is not quite clear on the requirements in this respect so I leave it to the author of the question to decide.